# Why first set a variable and then export it instead of setting and exporting in one command?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

If `gpg-agent` is executed, it outputs data that can be processed by a shell directly, e.g.:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-apeOFqMF3292/agent.3292; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=3293; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 3293;
```

Why is `gpg-agent` doing this? I've seen more programs doing it. Did shells in the past not support `export var=val`? Which shells do not support this alternative shell built-in?

I'm working with bash in Kubuntu.

Comment: Just a guess but this is probably something `bash` supports but `sh` doesn't.

Comment: @ultra: `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash` on my system which supports `export var=val` too. What shell are you talking about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The traditional Bourne shell didn't support combining them (although the System V one let you omit the `;`; the 4.2BSD / SunOS shell didn't).  It was added by the Korn shell (crossing the Bourne shell's `export` with `csh`'s `setenv`) and subsequently adopted by other shells and by POSIX.2.  Many commercial Unixes still ship the System V variant of the Bourne shell as `/bin/sh`, so retaining compatibility is a good idea for portability.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t apply to constant strings,
but a reason to get in the habit of doing this as two separate commands
is that `export FOO=$(mycmd)` masks the exit status from `mycmd`
— it will report success even if `mycmd` fails. 
See [How is the return status of a variable assignment determined?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/270828/80216)
and [the ShellCheck Wiki](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2155).