# How is the return status of a variable assignment determined?

Tags: bash, variable, command-substitution, exit-status

I have seen constructs in scripts such as this:

```
if somevar="$(somecommand 2>/dev/null)"; then
...
fi
```

Is this documented somewhere?  How is the return status of a variable determined and how does it relate to command substitution?  (For instance, would I get the same result with `if echo "$(somecommand 2>/dev/null)"; then`?)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is documented (for POSIX) in [Section 2.9.1 Simple Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01)
of The Open Group Base Specifications. 
There's a wall of text there; I direct your attention to the last paragraph:

> If there is a command name,
> execution shall continue as described in [Command Search and Execution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01). 
> If there is no command name,
> but the command contained a command substitution,
> the command shall complete with the exit status
> of the last command substitution performed. 
> Otherwise, the command shall complete with a zero exit status.

So, for example,

```
   Command                                         Exit Status
$ FOO=BAR                                   0 (but see also the note from icarus, below)
$ FOO=$(bar)                                Exit status from "bar"
$ FOO=$(bar)$(quux)                         Exit status from "quux"
$ FOO=$(bar) baz                            Exit status from "baz"
$ foo $(bar)                                Exit status from "foo"
```

This is how bash works, too. 
But see also the “not so simple” section at the end.

[phk](//unix.stackexchange.com/users/117599/phk), in his question [Assignments are like commands
with an exit status except when there’s command substitution?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/340997/80216), suggests

> … it appears as if an assignment itself counts as a command …
> with a zero exit value,
> but which applies before the right side of the assignment
> (e.g., a command substitution call…)

That’s not a terrible way of looking at it. 
A crude scheme for determining the return status of a simple command
(one not containing `;`, `&`, `|`, `&&` or `||`) is:

- Scan the line from left to right until you reach the end
  or a command word (typically a program name).
- If you see a variable assignment,
  the return status for the line just might be 0.
- If you see a command substitution — i.e., `$(…)` —
  take the exit status from that command.
- If you reach an actual command (not in a command substitution),
  take the exit status from that command.
- The return status for the line is the last number you encountered.
  Command substitutions *as arguments* to the command,
  e.g., `foo $(bar)`, don’t count; you get the exit status from `foo`. 
  To paraphrase [phk’s notation](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/340997/80216), the behavior here is

  ```
    temporary_variable  = EXECUTE( "bar" )
    overall_exit_status = EXECUTE( "foo", temporary_variable )
  ```

But this is a slight oversimplification. 
The overall return status from

```
A=$(cmd1)  B=$(cmd2)  C=$(cmd3)  D=$(cmd4)  E=mc2
```

is the exit status from `cmd4`. 
The `E=` assignment that occurs after the `D=` assignment
does not set the overall exit status to 0.

[icarus](//unix.stackexchange.com/users/194382/icarus), in [his answer to phk’s question](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/340997/80216#341013),
raises an important point: variables can be set as readonly. 
The third-to-last paragraph in [Section 2.9.1 of the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) says,

> If any of the variable assignments attempt to assign a value to a variable
> for which the *readonly* attribute is set in the current shell environment
> (regardless of whether the assignment is made in that environment),
> a variable assignment error shall occur. 
> See [Consequences of Shell Errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01) for the consequences of these errors.

so if you say

```
readonly A
C=Garfield A=Felix T=Tigger
```

the return status is 1. 
It doesn’t matter if the strings `Garfield`, `Felix`, and/or `Tigger`
are replaced with command substitution(s) — but see notes below.

[Section 2.8.1 Consequences of Shell Errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01) has another bunch of text,
and a table, and ends with

> In all of the cases shown in the table
> where an interactive shell is required not to exit,
> the shell shall not perform any further processing
> of the command in which the error occurred.

Some of the details make sense; some don’t:

- The `A=` assignment sometimes *aborts* the command line,
  as that last sentence seems to specify. 
  In the above example, `C` is set to `Garfield`, but `T` is not set
  (and, of course, neither is `A`).
- Similarly, `C=$(cmd1)  A=$(cmd2)  T=$(cmd3)`
  executes `cmd1`
  but not `cmd3`.
  **But,** in my versions of bash (which include 4.1.X and 4.3.X),
  it *does* execute `cmd2`. 
  (Incidentally, this further impeaches phk’s interpretation
  that the exit value of the assignment applies
  before the right side of the assignment.)

### But here’s a surprise:

In my versions of bash,

```
readonly A
C=something A=something T=something cmd0
```

***does*** execute `cmd0`. 
In particular,

```
C=$(cmd1)   A=$(cmd2)   T=$(cmd3)   cmd0
```

executes `cmd1`
and `cmd3`,
but not `cmd2`. 
(Note that this is the opposite of its behavior when there is no command.) 
And it sets `T` (as well as `C`) in the environment
of `cmd0`. 
I wonder whether this is a bug in bash.

---

### Not so simple:

The first paragraph of this answer refers to “simple commands”. 
[The specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) says,

> A “simple command” is a sequence of optional variable assignments
> and redirections, in any sequence,
> optionally followed by words and redirections,
> terminated by a control operator.

These are statements like the ones in my first example block:

```
$ FOO=BAR
$ FOO=$(bar)
$ FOO=$(bar) baz
$ foo $(bar)
```

the first three of which include variable assignments,
and the last three of which include command substitutions.

But some variable assignments aren’t quite so simple. 
[bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) says,

> Assignment statements may also appear as arguments to
> the **`alias`**, **`declare`**, **`typeset`**, **`export`**, **`readonly`**,
> and **`local`** builtin commands (*declaration* commands).

For `export`, [the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export) says,

> ***EXIT STATUS***
>
>   0
>     All name operands were successfully exported.
>   >0
>     At least one name could not be exported, or the
>     `-p`
>     option was specified and an error occurred.

And POSIX doesn’t support `local`, but [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) says,

> It is an error to use **`local`** when not within a function. 
> The return status is 0 unless **`local`** is used outside a function,
> an invalid *name* is supplied, or *name* is a readonly variable.

Reading between the lines, we can see that declaration commands like

```
export FOO=$(bar)
```

and

```
local FOO=$(bar)
```

are more like

```
foo $(bar)
```

insofar as they ignore the exit status from `bar`
and give you an exit status based on the main command
(`export`, `local`, or `foo`). 
So we have weirdness like

```
   Command                                           Exit Status
$ FOO=$(bar)                                    Exit status from "bar"
                                                  (unless FOO is readonly)
$ export FOO=$(bar)                             0 (unless FOO is readonly,
                                                  or other error from “export”)
$ local FOO=$(bar)                              0 (unless FOO is readonly,
                                                  statement is not in a function,
                                                  or other error from “local”)
```

which we can demonstrate with

```
$ export FRIDAY=$(date -d tomorrow)
$ echo "FRIDAY   = $FRIDAY, status = $?"
FRIDAY   = Fri, May 04, 2018  8:58:30 PM, status = 0
$ export SATURDAY=$(date -d "day after tomorrow")
date: invalid date ‘day after tomorrow’
$ echo "SATURDAY = $SATURDAY, status = $?"
SATURDAY = , status = 0
```

and

```
myfunc() {
    local x=$(echo "Foo"; true);  echo "x = $x -> $?"
    local y=$(echo "Bar"; false); echo "y = $y -> $?"
    echo -n "BUT! "
    local z; z=$(echo "Baz"; false); echo "z = $z -> $?"
}

$ myfunc
x = Foo -> 0
y = Bar -> 0
BUT! z = Baz -> 1
```

Luckily [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) catches the error and raises [SC2155](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155),
which advises that

```
export foo="$(mycmd)"
```

should be changed to

```
foo=$(mycmd)
export foo
```

and

```
local foo="$(mycmd)"
```

should be changed to

```
local foo
foo=$(mycmd)
```

**Credit and Reference**

I got the idea of concatenating command substitutions —
`$(bar)$(quux)` — from Gilles’s answer to [How can I get bash to exit
on backtick failure in a similar way to pipefail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23026/80216),
which contains a lot of information relevant to this question.

Comment: Great, thank you!  For bonus points, do you know how `local` ties into this?  E.g. `local foo=$(bar)`?

Comment: For the second example (just `FOO=$(bar)`) it's worth noting that theoretically both the exit status *and* the assignment might play a role, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341013/117599

Comment: Great expansion!  Only part which threw me off is your use of "impeaches."  I see it is in fact a correct usage, but you might consider "discredits" as a more applicable term.  :)

Comment: @phk:  OK, done.  Be careful what you ask for; you may get it (maybe more than you wanted).  Or maybe less.  I didn’t address your comment directly because I don’t entirely understand it.  Why did you single out the second example (`FOO=$(bar)`)?  The *first three* examples (all the ones that begin with `FOO=`) have an exit status of 1 if `FOO` is read-only.

Comment: @Wildcard:  I’m glad you like it.  I’ve just updated it again; a big part of the version that you just read was wrong.  As long as you’re here, what do you think?  Is this a bug in bash, that `A=foo cmd` runs `cmd` even if `A` is read-only?

Comment: @G-Man First of all, thanks for the update! About your newest finding: Perhaps _"further processing of the command"_ only refers to the assignement "command" itself? I've come to the conclusion that it might be easier to always keep in mind that we are dealing here with an interpreted scripting language with an interpreter with different stages dealing mainly with strings. So in this case all the assignments in the command line are separate commands with a an empty token (not empty string!) return value.

Comment: @G-Man And they have no effect on the rest of the command line because that logic belongs to another (internal) stage where the command line is then interpreted as a whole instead of its parts. BTW. maybe also helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8965957/2261442 (see also the comments)

Comment: @phk:  (1) Interesting theory, but I’m not sure how it makes sense.  Take another look at the example just before my “surprise” heading.  If `A` is readonly, the command `C=value₁ A=value₂ T=value₃` sets `C` but not `T` (and, of course, `A` is not set) — the shell terminated processing the command line, ignoring `T=value₃`, because `A=value₂` is an error.  (2) Thanks for the link to the [SO] question — I’ve posted come comments on it.

Comment: @Wildcard "For bonus points, do you know how local ties into this?". Yes... `local=$(false)` has exit value `0` because (from the man page): `It is an error to use local when not within a function.  The return status is 0 unless local is used outside a function, an invalid name is supplied, or name is a readonly variable.`. This is not enough trollface on the world for the genius who designed it that way.

Comment: @David Tonhofer: (1) Thanks for the update and the extra research.  (2) Please don’t use backticks as quotes.  Use quotes as quotes.  (3) Please don’t put quotes entirely in italics; that’s what quotation marks are for.  This goes quadruple if the text you’re quoting already contains italics.  (4) I said ‘‘that’s what quotation marks are for’’, but, actually, when you’re introducing a multi-line quote in a post, it’s (IMNSHO) better to use blockquotes — … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  especially when you’re editing somebody else’s post, and he already uses blockquotes.  (Unfortunately, you can’t use blockquotes in comments.)  (5) Please don’t use `test` as an arbitrary identifier.  As I’m sure you know, it’s a shell builtin command, and that just makes things confusing.  (6) You reported only half of what you discovered!  I concede that Wildcard’s question focused your search, but, once you found [the shellcheck SC2155 error page](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155 "Declare and assign separately to avoid masking return values."), … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  why didn’t you report on everything it said?  (Also, you might want to familiarize yourself with basic terminology like “simple command”, so you don’t go around saying that statement 2 is an exception to statement 1 when it isn’t.)  (7) If you really want to post ugly, unconstructive, non-contributory, non-illuminating images in ***your own*** questions and answers, I won’t object (too much).  Please don’t deface my answer with such graffiti. P.S. The example in your comment — `local=$(false)` — is a typo. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I’ve decided to let you have the two points for the edit, since you found something important and put some effort into documenting it.  But please bear the above points in mind when you write on [SE], and particularly when you edit other people’s work.

Answer (score 2):

It is documented in Bash (`LESS=+/'^SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION' bash`):

> If  there  is a command name left after expansion ... .  Otherwise, the command exits. ... If there were no command substitutions, the command exits with a status of zero.

In other words (my words):

> If there is no command name left after expansion, and
>   no command substitutions were executed, the command line
>   exits with a status of zero.