# Why does local fn=$(...) mask the $? status code

Tags: bash

Two function definitions, the only difference is that the first combines the `local` storage keyword with the assignment, while the second separates them:

```
function foo {
    local fn=$(mktemp -p /path/does/not/exist 2>/dev/null)
    echo $?
}

function bar {
    local fn
    fn=$(mktemp -p /path/does/not/exist 2>/dev/null)
    echo $?
}

foo
bar
```

This echoes "0" then "1". I expect it to echo "1" then "1". It seems like the value of `$?` is the result of the assignment to local, rather than the result of the command substitution.

Why does bash 4.2.46(1)-release behave this way?

Comment: Interesting; my reading of [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) says "The return status (of the local builtin) is zero unless local is used outside a function, an invalid name is supplied, or name is a readonly variable."

Comment: You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157938/bash-exit-code-of-variable-assignment-to-command-substitution#comment38560986_20157997 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340997/assignments-are-like-commands-with-an-exit-status-except-when-theres-command-su

Comment: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-03/msg00007.html

Comment: (`local` in ZSH also behaves this way)

Comment: Bash 4.3 here, manual states for the `local` built in: `The
              return status is 0 unless local is used outside a function, an invalid  name  is  sup‐
              plied, or name is a readonly variable.`  Please re-read the manual for  your version of bash. It may be there already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought this behavior was documented explicitly, because it's such a
gotcha (especially when running bash scripts with `-o errexit`!), but
it doesn't seem to. My copy of the manual says the following (about
`global`, which behaves the same as `local` when within a function):

> The return status is zero unless an invalid option is encountered,
>   an attempt is made to define a function using ‘-f foo=bar’, an
>   attempt is made to assign a value to a readonly variable, an attempt
>   is made to assign a value to an array variable without using the
>   compound assignment syntax [...], one of the names is not a
>   valid shell variable name, an attempt is made to turn off readonly
>   status for a readonly variable, an attempt is made to turn off array
>   status for an array variable, or an attempt is made to display a
>   non-existent function with -f.

So it would appear that `local` is not a keyword in the sense that one
would expect in other programming languages: when an assignment-like
parameter is provided to `local`, that does not qualify the
initialization; rather, the `local` *built-in command* takes care of
making the assignment happen, and the return code is that of `local`
itself, not of the code possibly run in the initializer, and that
return code will only be non-zero in the list of conditions listed
above.

To perhaps answer the question in a more literal sense, as bishop
mentioned in a comment, bash maintainer Chet Ramey was once asked if
he would consider making `local` reflect failures happening during
assignment, and responded, in essence, that [assigning is not
`local`'s main
mission](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-03/msg00036.html):

> Because that's not what local and its siblings [...]  do.  These
>   builtins exist to assign and modify variable attributes.  As an
>   added feature, they support value assignment at the same time, but
>   the important function is the attribute setting.  They don't need to
>   know how the value was computed. [...] Since the function is setting
>   the attribute or value, the exit status should reflect whether or
>   not that succeeded.

It may be worth noting that the same behavior can also be observed in the `zsh` shell.

The solution is to separate the two operations:

```
local variable
variable=$( somecommand )

exit_status=$?
```