# Can I get the exit code from a sub shell launched with $(command)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution, exit-status

I am setting a variable like this:

```
myvar=$(command --params)
```

I want to check the exit code (`$?`) of my command afterwards.  Checking `$?` like this always returns `0` because it successfully set the variable to the output of the command.

Is it possible to get the return value of `command`?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340997/assignments-are-like-commands-with-an-exit-status-except-when-theres-command-su

Comment: The premise here is wrong; `$?` [only returns 0 if the command succeeded.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/270828/135943)  It's not simply "always 0 because of successful variable assignment."

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, it is possible without even getting too far out of your way:

```
$ $(exit 3); echo $?
3

$ foo="$(echo bar; exit 3)"; echo $?; echo $foo
3
bar
```

Comment: Gold! But I spent a few minutes noticing the quotation marks :)

Comment: Inside a function, if you use 'local', it seems to not work. Just FYI.

Comment: @cwingrav It works if you separate the `local` declaration from the assignment into two separate steps: `local var; var=$(exit 3); echo "$?"`

Comment: @Kusalananda - agreed. I should have updated my comment to include this (I figured it out shortly after).