# In bash, how can I retrieve the exit code of a subshell when using local

Tags: exit, exit-status, subshell

This question is close to others - [Can I get the exit code from a sub shell launched with $(command)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346878/can-i-get-the-exit-code-from-a-sub-shell-launched-with-command)

However there are no solutions I've found that allows me to get an exit code from a sub shell when using local and eval as in this example...

```
test() {
> local WHY="$(eval "echo 'test'"; exit 3)"; echo $?
> }
test
0
```

Comment: there was one or more Qs where this was debated at length, but of course there's a trivial solution for that: `local why; why=$(false); echo $?;` (btw, don't use uppercase names for local variables).

Comment: that did the trick, thanks :)

Comment: BTW, arguably, one shouldn't use all-uppercase for *any* shell variables that aren't defined by the shell itself -- see [the relevant POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), specifying that the shell and other POSIX-compliant tools may modify their behavior based only on all-caps environment variables, leaving variable names with at least one lowercase character safe for applications to use (relevant to shell variables that aren't explicitly exported since changing a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is simple: Do not use a single command but split:

```
test() {
    local why
    why="$(eval "echo 'test'"; exit 3)"; echo $?
}
test
3
```

The problem was that `local` is a builtin command with an own exit code...If you avoid that command at the same time as the variable assignment, you get the exit code from the subshell.